# asp.net Button event firing problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, button

I am using an asp Button the following way:

```
<asp:Button ID="ButtonSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="ButtonSave_Click" />
```

and the code of the handler looks something like this:

```
protected void ButtonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Authenticate();

   //some other code here

   //redirect to certain page here
}
```

While debugging, I put a breakpoint at Authenticate, but it seems that it doesn't enter the function, although the redirection takes place and i don't do any more redirecting in the file only this one.
I don't understand what's going on, so if anyone could help i would be very grateful.

Comment: is it "Stopping" at any breakpoints? or just this one...because maybe you don't have debugging correctly enabled and it's just ignoring any breakpoints you have...

Comment: i just checked, it doesn't stop at any breakpoints not even at the page load function, but as i can tell, debugging is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple possible reasons. Four:

- You are not actually surfing to the
  application (version) that's hooked
  into the debugger: something that may
  happen if you're using IIS to host
  the application at the same time as
  you're creating debug instances on
  the fly (check your ports).
- The app has gone 'out of sync'. Rebuild / reload.
- Make sure you're doing a 'debug' build.
- Make sure the options Enable ASP Debugging and Enable ASP.NET Debugging are not set to False